# Stuck trying to reference value from text input in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, extendscript

I am trying to create a plugin for Photoshop. My file structure is as follows (as recommended in Adobe's guidelines on building plugins):

My root folder contains two folders: client and host.
The client folder contains index.html and index.js.
Index.html provides the design and references both javascript docs.
Index.js contains references to the elements in index.html, and sends directions to trigger functions contained in the index.jsx folder mentioned below.

The host folder contains index.jsx, which contains all the functions that actually trigger photoshop's tools. To get this javascript code, I've used xtools on mac to convert the photoshop actions I've created into .jsx files.

I want my plugin to have a text box in which users can input a value (it has to be a number), and then hit a button to trigger a function, a part of which I need to contain the value of the number they entered.

In this example, the function will resize the image to the user's desired number of pixels.

(Note: - the script works perfectly when the number is static/preset within the function and the button simply triggers the function without any other input - I'm just struggling with getting the value from the text box into the function).

Here's the code on each document:

**index.html:**

```
<input type="text" id="resizeinput" placeholder="enter value in pixels">
<button id="resizebutton">Go!</button>
```

**Index.js:**

```
var customresize = document.querySelector("#resizebutton");

customresize.onclick = function() {
  csInterface.evalScript("ResizeCustom()");
};
```

**Index.jsx:**

```
cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
sTID = function(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };

//
//==================== Resize Custom ==============
//
function ResizeCustom() {
  // Image Size
  function step1(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc1.putUnitDouble(cTID('Wdth'), cTID('#Pxl'), 1234);
    desc1.putBoolean(sTID("scaleStyles"), true);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('CnsP'), true);
    desc1.putEnumerated(cTID('Intr'), cTID('Intp'), sTID("bicubicSmoother"));
    executeAction(sTID('imageSize'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };

  step1();      // Image Size
};
```

Where the JavaScript in index.jsx says "1234" is where I need to reference the value entered in the text box "#resizeinput".

My best bet so far was to replace 1234 with:
document.getElementById("#resizeinput").value)

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Index.js:

```
var customresize = document.querySelector("#resizebutton"),
    resizeInput = document.querySelector("#resizeinput");

customresize.onclick = function()
{
    csInterface.evalScript("ResizeCustom(" + resizeInput.value + ")");

};
```

in Index.jsx:

```
cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
sTID = function(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };

function ResizeCustom(_arg) {
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc1.putUnitDouble(cTID('Wdth'), cTID('#Pxl'), _arg);
    desc1.putBoolean(sTID("scaleStyles"), true);
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('CnsP'), true);
    desc1.putEnumerated(cTID('Intr'), cTID('Intp'), sTID("bicubicSmoother"));
    executeAction(sTID('imageSize'), desc1, DialogModes.NO);
};
```

Note that this doesn't do any checks (if you'll try to pass a string, there'll be an error).

p.s. in the world of Abdobe plugins are written in C++, and HTML panels are extensions. Just in Case :)

p.p.s I'd recommend checking Davide Barranca's blog with HTML Panels Tips, for example on passing data from JS to JSX: [HTML Panels Tips: #4 passing Objects from HTML to JSX](https://www.davidebarranca.com/2014/01/html-panels-tips-4-passing-objects-from-html-to-jsx/)